# How to find p-value in the logistic regression model

Tags: orange

Using orange canvas to build a logistic regression model, are there any widget to print out the p-value of variables?

I can only know how to print out the coefficient of the variables input but not the p-value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such widget in Orange.